# How to make a button redirect to another XML layout

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm making a button in xml(res / layout / activity_home.xml), like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/schkopwide" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/HTI"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:onclick="Intent i = new Intent(activity_store.xml);
        startActivity(i);"
        android:text="@string/HTI" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

so what should I add into this xml to let it redirect to another xml page (res / layout / activity_store.xml)?

Thank you

Comment: instead of posting question go through tutorials and developer docs ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out as below:

> ```
>  <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
>     android:onclick="start"
>     android:text="@string/HTI" />
> ```

In your main activity :

```
  Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityStore.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Here is your ActivityStore Class code:

> ```
>  public class ActivityStore extends Activity {
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);
>          }
>        }
> ```

Also add the activity into your mainfest file.

> ```
> <activity
>         android:name=".ActivityStore"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"/ >
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If you Want to show two different layouts in Same Activity, then **ViewSwitcher** is best layout.

You can add multiple layouts in ViewSwithcher. And Replace them by using **viewswitcher.next();**  function.

```
<ViewSwitcher

android:id="@+id/viewswitcher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<!--   Add Two View’s Here -- >

</ViewSwitcher>
```

You can take reference from this link: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/viewswitcher

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the launch of an Intent inside the onclick parameter in XML. You have to do it by code.

In your code:

```
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityStore.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

And in the OnCreate of the ActivityStore class, put this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);
    }
```

NOTE: I supposed that yous activity_store class is called ActivityStore

Comment: where should I add these files






















 <a href=http://soundfrost.softonic.de/ >youtube downloader</a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on Android documentation :

- Activity
- OnClickListener
- Intent

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this,

Statically include XML layouts inside other XML layouts. use `include`. Add the below code in your activity_store.xml

```
  <include layout="@layout/activity_home"/>
```

Sure you will get solution.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way would be to create an Activity with another xml attached to it and then use intent.